# Arithmetic operation in bash script

Tags: bash

I saw an expression `a=($(cat))` which I am not able to understand from it's working mechanism perspective.

Functionally it takes input from the standard input and assigns it to variable `a` (which forms an array).

My understanding is , when shell executes the inner parenthesese it executes the `cat` command which brings the standard input, and when you type a few lines on the standard input and press `CTRL+D` it returns the lines to the outer parenthesese which then assign the lines to an array `a`.

My question is why this expression gives error when I remove the `$` and write it as `a=((cat))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `$(..)` is a command substitution syntax to run commands on. The `cat` in your example run in a sub-shell under this construct. Without it the command `cat` and `(` are interpreted literally which the shell does not like

From the [bash(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

> **Command Substitution**
>
> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command name. There are two forms:
>   `$(command)` (or) `command`
>
> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted.

The arithmetic operator in `bash` is `$((..))` which is **not** the syntax you are using in your example

Comment: so the output of the cat command should be treated as a command in command substitution ? I guess my syntax is an arithmetic one because there is an `=` operator .

Comment: @Vicky: You treat as if the `cat` command is run in a separate shell and its output (whatever read from stdin) is stored in to the array `a`

Comment: I get it now , from your command substitution explanation , Thanks Inian

Comment: I ran into another similar problem `read array;
arr=(echo $array)` executes echo and assigns the output to arr but `a=(cat file.txt)` assigns "cat file.txt" to `a`, it is not assigning contents of file.txt to `a` I guess cat in later case is being teated as a simple string  in absence of command substitution operator `$(
..)`  but how is echo able  to execute without command substitution.

Comment: @Vicky: Do ask it as a question under `bash`. As such the context of your old question is complete